# R-Squared of alternative model

Tags: pandas, scipy, statsmodels

In order to reduce the influence of outliers and obtain a more robust regression, I've applied a winsorization technique to modify the values of a series ('x').  I then regress these values against series 'y'.

The R-squared of this model is naturally much higher, but I'm not making the right comparison.

How do I use scipy or statsmodels to obtain the R-squared of the **original** data using the beta estimates from the winsorized model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to calculate it yourself, essentially by replicating the formula for rsquared.

For example

```
>>> res_tmp = OLS(np.random.randn(100), np.column_stack((np.ones(100),np.random.randn(100, 2)))).fit()
>>> y_orig = res_tmp.model.endog
>>> res_tmp.rsquared
0.022009069788207714

>>> (1 - ((y_orig - res_tmp.fittedvalues)**2).sum() / ((y_orig - y_orig.mean())**2).sum())
0.022009069788207714
```

The last expression would apply to your case if `res_tmp.fittedvalues` are the predicted or fitted values of your winsorized model, and `y_orig` is your original unchanged response variable. This definition of R squared applies if there is a constant in the model.

**Note**: The most frequent naming for the linear model corresponds to `y = X b`, where y is the response variable and X are the explanatory variables. IIUC, then you reversed the labeling in your question.